# fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория

Tags: git, сервер, github

Пытался развернуть

https://github.com/arguman/arguman.org/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Вот эти команды прекрастно отработали:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Create Virtual Environment

```
mkvirtualenv argumanorg

dima@komp:~/Q_A_site/arguman$ mkvirtualenv argumanorg
mkvirtualenv: команда не найдена
```

А на клонирование гитхаба вообще ругается:

```
git clone git@github.com:arguman/arguman.org.git

dima@komp:~/Q_A_site/arguman$ git clone git@github.com:arguman/arguman.org.git
Клонирование в «arguman.org»…
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.118.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.
```

Comment: Если вам что то не нравиться оставьте, комментарий. _П.С. я не знаю английского языка и посему задал вопрос._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `github.com` можно клонировать код [двумя](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use) способами:

Используя SSH. Это то, как пытаетесь сделать вы, но просто так это работать не будет. Сначала нужно [создать SSH ключи](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), добавить их в аккаунт github и только потом пытаться клонировать.

Используя HTTPS. Способ намного проще (ничего настраивать не нужно) и рекомендуется github. `git clone https://github.com/arguman/arguman.org.git` тогда оно будет работать.

По поводу `mkvirtualenv`. Его необходимо после установки дополнительно настроить, как это делать описано [тут](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/4.8.4/).